# Rails 4 -Nested Models and Simple Form partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am trying to make an app in Rails 4.

I have a projects, project questions and a project answers model.

**my models**

```
class Project
  has_many :project_questions, dependent: :destroy#, through: :projects
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_questions
end

class ProjectQuestions
  belongs_to :project#, counter_cache: true
  has_many :project_answers, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_answers
end

class ProjectAnswer
  belongs_to :project_question#, counter_cache: true  
  belongs_to :user 
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :projects do
  # patch '/toggle-draft', to 'projects#toggle_draft', as: 'toggle_draft'
    resources :project_questions do
      resources :project_answers
    end
  end
```

In my **projects_controller**, I have permitted params for project questions and answers as follows:

```
project_question_attributes: [:title, :content, :user_id, :project_id,
      project_answer_attributes: [:answer, :project_question_id]],
```

These params are also permitted in the Project questions and project answers controllers.

In my projects view, I want to render a partial that I have made in my project_questions view folder.

**projects/show**

```
  <%= link_to 'Ask a question', new_project_question_path %> <% end %>
  <%= render 'project_questions/pqps' %>
```

In my project_questions partial which is called **_pqps**, I have;

```
<div class="containerfluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

      <% f.simple_fields_for :project_questions, @project.project_questions.build do |f| %>
          <div class="categorytitle">
            <%= f.title %>
          </div>
          <div class="generaltext">
            <%= f.content %>
          </div>
          <%= render 'project_answers/show' %>
          <span class="editproject">   <% if current_user.id ==  @project.creator_id %>
            <%= link_to 'Answer this question', new_project_answer_path %>
              <% end %>
          </span>

      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I try this, I get an error that says:

> undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#:0x0000010a11ce60>

I thought I was defining `f` at the beginning of the opening line of the **_pqps form**.

I'm really struggling to get a grip with coding. Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Comment: On which file you get this error? Can you see logs and tell

Comment: Hi Abhi, its in the projects show

Comment: Then pass it like `<%= render 'project_answers/show', :locals => {:f => f} %>`

Comment: do you mean answers as well as questions?

Comment: I can see you are using this `<%= render 'project_answers/show' %>` code at only one place.

Comment: It's stuck on the same error in the projects show (after I do as you suggested) undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#<Class:0x0000010139de18>:0x00000103910920>

Comment: Now, it's difficult to suggest without seeing logs

Comment: How many places should it be used in?

Comment: ok, thanks anyway. I'll try and figure out how to find logs

Answer (score 0):

You use `f.simple_fields_for` in pqps, but `f` is not defined anywhere.
You have to define it using `simple_form_for` somewhere. I don't know exactly where – it depends on your own needs, but if, say, the whole form is inside _pqps:

```
<div class="containerfluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
      <%= simple_form_for @project do |f| %>
        <% f.simple_fields_for :project_questions, @project.project_questions.build do |f| %>
          # ...
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If form "starts" outside "_pqps" partial, then you have to pass `f` as a local parameter:

```
<%= render 'project_questions/pqps', f: f %>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but I get an error that says: undefined local variable or method `f' for

Comment: That error means you are trying to access `f` somewhere outside of the block. Make sure you access it between `<%= simple_form_for @project do |f| %>` and `<% end %>` for that block.

Answer (score 0):

projects_controller

```
def show
  @project_questions = @project.project_questions.build
end
```

View

```
<%= simple_form_for @project_questions do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title%>
  <%= f.input :content %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but then I get an error that says: No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"project_answers", :id=>"70", :project_id=>nil, :project_question_id=>nil, :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:project_id, :project_question_id]